# Can unlimited kinetic energy be stored in superfluid helium?

Tags: science-based, physics, weapons, energy, kinetic-weapons

Liquid helium can be in a state of superfluidity — meaning it can flow with zero internal friction. Let's assume that for whatever reason that this form of helium is present in large amounts. Could this be practically used to store energy?  Say by letting all members of a society contribute on a fixed time-base to its motion, or by other means. The helium is kept at a fixed temperature, experiences no internal friction, and as such, it can prolong its state of motion indefinitely (like the current in a superconductor but with a lot more kinetic energy).

Can the helium absorb unlimited amounts of kinetic energy? Would the temperature rise if the kinetic energy stored exceeds a certain value? What would happen if this helium were dropped on something? Would the stored kinetic energy act like a bomb?

Comment: This would look like a "liquid flywheel". In theory, it can store a good amount of kinetic energy, but this would still be only a limited amount - container would have to be strong enough to contain this rotating liquid.

Answer (score 9):

Superfluid helium is such only below 2.17 K. This means that, to keep in that condition, you need to continuously remove energy from it, because, you know, practically everything else is hotter than it.

And to induce motion into it (the only way to benefit from its superfluidity) you would need to physically insert some sort of paddle in it and that would slowly but steadily lead to an increase in temperature.

Also don't forget that helium is the second lightest element in the universe, meaning that per unit volume it has a very low mass. Kinetic energy is proportional to mass, so it would be a very volume intensive storage.

Comment: Say it's in a low temperature vessel. A metal mixer can be immerse in it at will. This metal has zero kelvin temperature (or a bit more).

Comment: does a paddle even work with a superfluid?

Comment: @ths good point. Since paddling efficiency is in large part a function of viscosity, I imagine a superfluid would simply flow around any paddle as it has no friction with itself to keep it in front  of the paddle.

Comment: How can you paddle a superfluid?  I think you have to use other means to induce motion, *not* a paddle.  Note that rotating superfluid will form quantized vortices rather than moving like water.

Answer (score 6):

**No**

@L.Dutch is correct (and I upvoted his answer), the [laws of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics) are in play, assuring that the energy required to maintain the condition for storage will draw away from that storage (if not be in excess of what you could store)...

... but more to the point, it's impossible to store an infinite amount of energy in a finite medium no matter what it is or how the energy came to pass. Such a thing would be a "[perpetual motion machine](https://www.livescience.com/55944-perpetual-motion-machines.html)."

Let's ignore that, for a moment. Another problem is that as you add energy to a system, that energy affects the thermal equilibrium of that system. In short, the more energy you store, the more energy you'd need to keep the helium cold enough to store anything.

The last problem I can think of off the top of my head is that the colder you make the helium (or any other storage medium), the less energy you can store in it in the first place. This is why batteries become weak when they get cold.

So, no. You can't do what you're proposing with one exception...

All stored energy of any kind and any amount can "act like a bomb" — it's only a question of whether or not the "explosion" can overcome the inertia of the bomb's container and still do enough damage to be useful. Gratefully, most of the stored energy humanity encounters on a day to day basis isn't enough to do any harm when catastrophically released.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128232/discussion-on-answer-by-jbh-can-unlimited-kinetic-energy-be-stored-in-superfluid).

Answer (score -4):

In a nice article linked in one of the comments it is shown that you can make the superfluid helium maintained for arbitrarily large flow velocities. These velocities have specific values;

> Here we demonstrate that superfluidity can be completely restored for specific, arbitrarily large flow velocities above the critical velocity.

This means that you can store a huge kinetic energy in the rotating helium

Assuming a wonder material to contain the helium and a magic device to impart velocity to the helium, it becomes possible to make black hole bombs. With a considerable masd. The Earth has a Schwarzschild radius of a few centimeter so the bomb, say a spherically symmetric containing vessel of one meter radius, will be about 70 Earth masses big. Now it has to be thrown...

Comment: You severely misunderstood the implications of what the article said. Please read it more carefully, and look at what would happen when you approach anything near those energy levels.